# Yeshiva Kayitz for non mesivta bochur?

Tags: yeshiva-school, summer

Do you have to be enrolled in a Mesivta/Yeshiva Ketana to go to Yeshiva Kayitz? I'm in process of becoming a Ger Tzedek and I'd like to go to Yeshiva, I'm only 15, turning 16 soon in the summer and next summer my parents allowed me to go to Israel for Yeshiva meaning a Summer Program since they want me to get a secular education here (in a country without a yeshiva for that matter).

So I was wondering basically if they allow boys who don't attend a Mesivta to go to Yeshiva Kayitz?

Comment: You need to talk to your rabbi to find the right program for you. Some programs will be happy to work with you and some will be less than helpful. Really depends on the people involved. You could try Ohr Hatorah in Crown heights. It’s a yeshiva for be’alei teshuva. Ohr Samayach or Aish might also be places to find out more info

Comment: Are your parents gerei tzedek as well?

Comment: Maybe NCSY Kollel would be a good option

Comment: the rabbi who is helping you convert should be helping you with your educational needs as well.

Comment: I'm gonna ask him but he's out of town and I wanted to know if it's just outright impossible to go to kayitz if you're not a bochur at a regular mesivta. Also no my parents are not gerei tzedek just me.

Comment: There are  definitely programs available. Ask your Rabbi for recommendations. The system is not so standardized. Some programs will work and some won't.

Comment: It's not that anyone has a problem with you not having a diploma from Kayitz. The issue is your skillset for learning chumash, mishnah, etc. As @N.T. says above, some programs will be able to accommodate a relative beginner, others not so much